# SQLAlchemy sqlite не работает каскадное удаление

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Я сделал таблицы в sqlite  и связал их через внешние ключи. В параметре DELETE поставил Cascad.Когда я удаляю запись в родительской таблице **через  Navicat**  - записи в дочерних таблицах удаляются автоматом.
Но когда делаю удаление **в SQLAlchemy** - удаляется только сама та запись, а дочерние остаются. Я знаю, что  в sqllite по-умолчанию отключена поддержка внешних ключей. Поэтому я ее включаю, но это не помогает. Вот мой код:

```
    def __init__(self):
       dbName = 'notebook.db'
       self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db/" + dbName)
       self.engine.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')
```

Удаление делает метод:

```
    @classmethod
def delete(cls, id):
    model = cls()
    model = model.findById(id)
    if model == None:
        return False
    model.__init__()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=model.engine)
    session = Session()
    try:
        session.delete(model)
        session.commit()
        return True
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        model.addToLog(e)
        sys.exit()
```

Кто может подсказать,в чем я ошибся? Почему через SQLAlchemy удаляется только 1 запись, а связанные не трогаются в БД, а если удалять эту же запись в Navicat - все работает как надо и дочерние записи автоматом удаляются через внешний ключ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В документации приводится пример
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support
Т.е. добавив в начало, перед объявлением классаи инициализацией соединения с БД такой код - все заработало

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```